# Advance Django app

Tags: python, django, angularjs, web-applications, backbone.js

I am a little new to Django framework. I have pass the Django's tutorial and I would like to ask a very simple question. if I want to build an advance web app with database except of django framework(server side), do I really need to choose also a client framework like angular.js or backbone?
Can I do the client side without involving a specific framework?
I ask this question as a matter of cautious and saving time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to choose any other client framework, you can use solely Django - it's a full featured framework which is designed to be flexible enough for all your needs.

There's a small learning curve (as with all good frameworks) but it's really not hard, especially if you have a background in Python.

My advice would be to just play with it. Follow the tutorial making the voting application and then move onto creating forms, playing with the `models` and `forms`, making everything work cohesively and then once you're familiar with things you can begin writing your advanced web application.

Also if you get stuck then there's the `#django` channel on Freenode (IRC) which can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Django is a full-featured MVC application where you generate the views on the serverside. I would say that is redundant with a single-page web application framework like Angular. If you use that, and you want to stick with Python, then you would probably be better served with a REST API library like Flask.

Neither is "better." It depends on which programming model you prefer and the requirements for your application.